# Spring Return after Validation

Tags: java, spring, http, redirect, forward

I have a page to add a user "/user/userAdd". In GET, i populate a list of Countries. In POST, i validate the User object from the formsubmit. If it has error, i return back to the same page with error msg. My problem is I just do a simple return "/user/userAdd"; the Country list is not populated. If I do a return "redirect:/user/userAdd"; i am loosing the previous user input. How should I handle this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/userAdd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getUserAdd(Model aaModel) {
    aaModel.addAttribute("user", new User());

    List<Country> llistCountry = this.caService.findCountryAll();

    aaModel.addAttribute("countrys", llistCountry);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/userAdd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postUserAdd(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
        BindingResult aaResult, SessionStatus aaStatus) {
    if (aaResult.hasErrors()) {

        return "/user/userAdd";
    } else {
        user = this.caService.saveUser(user);

        aaStatus.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing similar issues in my spring project. I would recommend changing your POST method to following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/userAdd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postUserAdd(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
        BindingResult aaResult, Model aaModel, SessionStatus aaStatus) {
    if (aaResult.hasErrors()) {
        List<Country> llistCountry = this.caService.findCountryAll();
        aaModel.addAttribute("countrys", llistCountry);   

        return "/user/userAdd";
    } else {
        user = this.caService.saveUser(user);

        aaStatus.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

Here, the list is again added to the model and it will also retain the previously selected values(if any) in UI.

Hope this helps